# My design doesn't work right

Tags: magento-2.1, theme, magento2.2, theme-overriding

Hey I am new to **Magento** and I am trying to see what I can do.
I have watched a lot of videos that tell me "how to change theme?"

But in my **`"store>general>design"`** I don't get the right possibility too change my theme.

I got a search engine robot instead of category change.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the theme under `Content > Design > Configuration` and then click edit behind website/store/store-view.

Comment: The video i saw showt mee that it was  "store>general>design" for the hole store and i try ed what all of you said. and that dident work. At that time noting that i change would do what  wanted. after reset all i try ed again and that work

Answer (score 0):

Please find the Below Screen shot to change the theme.

Please follow below steps

In admin Magento 2:Content > Design (Configuration) > Action Change Theme

https://prnt.sc/ivaug7

Answer (score 0):

To change your store theme with your custom theme just do follow the below steps.

1. Create your theme at the below location.

> Magento_root/app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{Custom_theme}

2. Just traverse to the below location from your **backend(Admin)**

> Content > Design > Configuration

3. In Design Configuration just click on any of the edit button
   **(preferred last one)**
4. Select your custom theme into the **Applied Theme**
5. Do set your Pagination, HTML Head, Header, Footer & other contents you want & save it

> Note: Make sure while you are ding this your cache is disabled & run
>   the below command from your Magento root directory.
>
> ```
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
> php bin/magento cache:flush
> ```